# *NgFor does not display the data

Tags: angular, httprequest, graphql, ngfor

I'm writing my first Angular2 application.

I have a `BankAccountService` that fetches data from my backend server and a `bank-account.component` which uses this service to simply display an unsorted list of the accountNumbers.

Debugging through chrome devtool i was able to see that the data is fetched correctly and stored in the `bankAccounts` data member, but for some reason the `ul` shows nothing.

BankAccountService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {client} from '../app.module';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {ObservableQuery} from "apollo-client";

@Injectable()
export class BankAccountService{
    bankAccounts: any[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.queryBankAccounts();
    }

    queryBankAccounts(): any{
        let queryObservable: ObservableQuery = client.watchQuery({
            query: gql`
              {
                bankAccounts {
                  id
                  accountNumber
                  userOwners{
                    firstName
                  }
                 bankId
                  branchId
                  transactions{
                    amount
                    payerId
                    recipientId
                  }
                }
              }
            `,
            pollInterval: 50
        });

        let subscription = queryObservable.subscribe({
            next: ({ data }) => {
                this.bankAccounts = data;
            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
            }
        });
    }

    getBankAccounts(){
        return this.bankAccounts;
    }
}
```

bank-account.component:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {BankAccountService} from "../services/BankAccountService";

@Component({
    selector: 'bank-account',
    template: `<ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let account of bankAccounts">
                        {{account.accountNumber}}
                    </li>
               </ul>`,
    providers: [BankAccountService]
})
export class BankAccountComponent{
    bankAccounts: any[] = [];

    constructor(bankAccountService: BankAccountService){
        this.bankAccounts = bankAccountService.getBankAccounts();
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light, i can't seem to understand my mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ngOnInit method to make the call of bankAccountService.getBankAccounts()

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, ive tried what you suggested and now it looks like the array is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the service fills its bankAccounts data asynchronously (when it gets results from the server) while your component tries to read the data synchronously.  At the time the component reads the data, the service is still waiting for that data to arrive from the back end.

The better design is to make the service's `getBankAccounts()` be an Observable that will emit the data when it is ready.  Your component would then subscribe to this service and only initialize the view once the data arrives.

**service**

```
//make this observable into a class property
queryObservable:ObservableQuery = client.watchQuery({
    ...
});

//return the observable that will emit the data
getBankAccounts():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.queryObservable;
}
```

**component**

```
//don't set it to anything, so the *ngIf will work in the template 
bankAccounts: any[];

//better to do this here than in the constructor
ngOnInit(){
    this.bankAccountService.getAccounts().subscribe(
        data => this.bankAccounts = data
    )
}
```

**template**

```
<!-- only show the list IF the data is available -->
<ul *ngIf="bankAccounts">
    <li *ngFor="let account of bankAccounts">
        {{account.accountNumber}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I don't go over it here, but an alternative (if you don't want to use `*ngIf`) is to leave the service as I described, then in the component set `bankAccounts = service.getBankAccounts()`, and in the template use the `async` pipe, which expects an Observable and will automatically display the data once the Observable emits.

Answer (score 6):

That's because async function is getting data, but you are trying to display it before it is fetched, therefore, you are iterating through an empty array. You can solve this problem easily by not initializing array (change `bankAccounts: any[] = [];` to `bankAccounts: any[];`) and surrounding your `<ul>` tags with `<div *ngIf="bankAccounts"></div>`. That way, `bankAccounts` array will be undefined until data is fetched and your `*ngFor` loop will be executed right after array is populated thanks to `*ngIf` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, seems like you're right, is there a cleaner way or any kind of best practice for this type of stuff? placing `*ngIf` seems a bit dirty

Comment: Actually, after trying your suggestion it doesn't look like it solves it, I've surrounded the `<ul>` with a `<div *ngIf="bankAccounts">` and its still empty.. is there a way to debug the DOM for those parts of angular `ngFor` , `ngIf` etc?

Comment: I confirm that *ngFor loop is being executed only if the array it uses is not empty.